# Random assortment of numbers to variables

Tags: c#, function

I'm an ex-python programmer and I've taken to trying to learn a "grown up" language which is C#. But I need help with functions. In python you could write a funtion such as

```
def mainloop:
    x = random.randint(1,100)
    print (x)
    mainloop()
mainloop()
```

and it would go back to the funtion mainloop(). Here's the problem code I'm working on.

```
public int getValue()
{
    List<int> usedNumbers = new List<int>();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int tempValue = rnd.Next(0, 27);

    if (usedNumbers.Contains(tempValue))
    {
        // Go back to getValue() to have the tempValue get a new value
    }
    else
    {
        usedNumbers.Add(tempValue);
        return tempValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot determine what your end goal is. Do you want a method to just return a random number or are you wanting a method to return a random number while keeping a running tally?

Comment: Yep, hard to know what you're trying to do. The point is `usedNumbers` is not needed because you will never get more than one number on that function

Answer (score 5):

It seems that, based on the signature, that you want this:

```
private Random rnd = new Random();
public int getValue()
{
    return rnd.Next(0, 27);
}
```

But based on the content of your method it appears that you want to return a series of random numbers without repetition.

In that case you need this:

```
private Random rnd = new Random();
public IEnumerable<int> getValues()
{
    foreach (var value in Enumerable.Range(0, 26).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()))
    {
        yield return value;
    }
}
```

You could even shorten this to:

```
private Random rnd = new Random();
public IEnumerable<int> getValues()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 26).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next());
}
```

If I then did this:

```
var x = String.Join(", ", getValues());
```

I would get something like this:

> 2, 15, 13, 3, 24, 8, 9, 20, 10, 5, 23, 6, 0, 17, 11, 7, 22, 4, 18, 1, 12, 21, 16, 19, 25, 14

Answer (score 0):

Your code is recursive so I changed it a little bit so it works. Note however that solving this using recursion is not at all optimal and most certainly will result in StackOvrflowException. The solution suggested by @Enigmativity is absolutely the way to go. This one is more to humor you with a theoretical solution that follows your original suggestion.

Because there is no real stop condition in your code I added a simple one. The recursive call will stop after randomly creating 5 distinguish itmes:

```
public static List<int> getValue(List<int> numbers)
{
    List<int> usedNumbers = numbers;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int tempValue = rnd.Next(0, 27);

    if (usedNumbers.Count == 5)
    {
        return usedNumbers;
    }

    if (usedNumbers.Contains(tempValue))
    {
        return getValue(usedNumbers);
    }
    else
    {
        usedNumbers.Add(tempValue);
        return getValue(usedNumbers);
    }
}
```

Let me just stress it again: this is only to show how to solve this problem using recursive approach. Real world solution is already provided in other answers.